# How to clear the content of subview before drawing

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uibutton

i use two blocks to draw some buttons on my subview dynamically. One calculates frames for Portrait mode and the other does for Landscape. It works well but when i rotate, it writes over the old ones. Hence, some of my buttons come twice. Here is my code of detecting the oriantation:

```
//i have defined blocks in viewDidLoad: and everything is ok till here
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), PortraitBlock);        
        }       
        else 
        { 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), LandscapeBlock);
               }
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
                interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
                interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
                interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
```

Now, how can i clean the view i add the buttons on?

Note: I add buttons on a UIView object, and that object too is on a UIScrollView object

Comment: @illis if the buttons are added twice time then give tag to buttons  and check if a button exist then dnt add it

Comment: You do not need to redraw buttons each time you rotate the device. Just move them to appropriate place and change the appearance if it needed.

Comment: I need more information about your particular situation to be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> hi,.,
>
> Try below code with this all your button which you alloc on the view
>   will be remove.

```
for(UIButton *view in yourview.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: i did try this in blocks and later on the rotation method. but it removes all the scrollview. a blank screen appears

Comment: This will remove ALL subviews from yourview.

Comment: Mark your button's view with some tag value, to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Before removing the views from your view first check the class and then remove it. After that you can add your buttons on the screen based on the orientation.

```
for(UIView *view in [View to add buttons].subviews)
{
   if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

If you are using any `customButton` the mention your `customButtonClassName` in place of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add new buttons at all. Just change the old frames.

If you *need* to add new buttons. Just remove the old ones!? To remove all subviews, you could use:

```
for(UIView* view in self.view.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: any UI changes have to be done on the main thread, why are you calling those blocks asynchronously? what is crashing!? any logs?

Comment: I tried your code inside of my blocks but an empty screen comes. No crash but no result too